Breaker trips when plugging into wall outlet(receptacle) directly, but not when using extension
I have recently run into a really weird situation. I have a two-socket wall outlet(receptacle) in the living room, and it is connected to a 15 amps breaker with arc fault indicator. I can also ascertain that this outlet is the only thing connected to this breaker. Now, I am running two computers on this outlet, one is plugged directly into the upper socket of the outlet, the other one is plugged into a 6-socket extension, which is plugged into the lower socket of the outlet. The 6-socket extension also has other stuffs like lamps and phone charger on it. In short, everything is powered by this same wall outlet.
The breaker suddenly tripped today. At first, I assumed that running two PC's on the same outlet could be a little too much, so I did some testing. Then, I figured out some really strange stuff that I cannot explain.

If I plug one PC into the wall outlet directly and the other PC into the 6-socket extension (which is also plugged into the same wall outlet), the breaker trips when I turn both PC on at the same time. I've tested many times and it trips guaranteed.

If I plug both PC's into the 6-socket extension, however, I can turn them on at the same time WITHOUT the breaker ever tripping. I know this because I let both PC's run for a long time and the breaker does not trip. Yet, had I plugged one PC into the outlet directly it woukd trip within 60s every single time. It didn't matter if I used the upper socket or the lower socket of the outlet, as I tried both.


This is really confusing for me, as I don't understand its behaviour. It'd seem like that in both situations, both PC's get their power from the same outlet and the current always run through the same breaker anyways. More importantly, I need to know if this behaviour is normal and if I need to get any repairs done.
Some additional information:

I live in Canada so it's 120V AC here
By wall outlet I mean a receptacle that looks like this, having an upper and a lower socket
The 6-socket extension comes with surge protection, but I think its irrelevant as it never triggered
After the breaker trips, when I reset it the ARC FAULT light lights up for 5s then goes off. I figured this is normal as other breakers do the same if I manually trip them(via their "test" button) and reset them.


The answers so far don't address the fact that it's an AFCI breaker. Might be important, might not be -- but when it trips, does it show an overcurrent condition or an arc fault condition?

What make/product line are your circuit breakers?

@SortofDamocles It shows an arc fault condition

@ThreePhaseEel It's Siemens that I'm using

Does "_ I turn both PC on at the same time_" mean you flip both power buttons simultaneously (double the in-rush current), or do you turn one on and then the other (so that they are then both on at the same time)?

@TripeHound When I was testing I turn them on at the same time but initially I think they were just on at the same time, not turned on at the same time.

Do the PC plugs feel looser in the wall outlet than in the six socket extension?
I would turn off the breaker and double check there is no power.
Remove the face plate and see if the outlet is loose in the box(moves side to side).
Check that ground is not too close to the hot screws.
Check all screws are tight on the wires.
If the plug/s do feel looser, I would take pictures of how the outlet/receptacle is wired and replace with a new one.
AFCI breakers sense electric arks/sparks on the circuit.  Loose connections can cause sparks.

I will just add that they are also prone to "nuisance trips" because some electrical loads look like arcs even when they aren't. Siemens is a known culprit of nuisance trips.  https://www.classaction.org/news/siemens-arc-fault-circuit-interrupters-prone-to-nuisance-tripping-class-action-alleges

Thank you. I have checked all screws and they are indeed tight, I ended up moving one of my computers to another location. It doesn't seem the plugs are loose either

Two things are probably at play here.

With everything else plugged in, the inrush/ start-up current is enough to trip your breaker.  That is, your load is borderline. And you should distribute the load.

The extension cord is limiting the current. That is, you are close to its limit as well. It also delays the current a tiny tiny bit, but that's not at play here.



The extension is acting like a buffer, or providing a more resistant current flow, or a different current pathway that somehow avoids tripping the breaker.
This is actually similar to my situation with my fridge in the garage. I have second fridge that when i plug directly into a GFCI outlet, it trips, but if i use an extension cord, it does not.
Technically, you're "bypassing" the safety mechanism which is not recommended, strictly speaking.
